# Serverless - the connection between node version update and 'No file matches include / exclude patterns' Error

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I attempted to upgrade my stack to use Node.js version 16 instead of Node.js 14.
However, following the update, I encountered the following error during deployment: `No file matches include/exclude patterns`.

I followed advice from various sources and removed the `package.exclude` from my config entry, which eliminated the error. However, this action resulted in my serverless setup crashing after deployment with `Runtime.ImportModuleError` errors 
It seems that the node_modules are no longer linked to the serverless file, preventing it from running.

I've searched thoroughly about this error and found some explanation, none of them explain how this error can pop after a node upgrade.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance you could provide

My configuration:

```
  ...
 service: ...,
        plugins: [
            'serverless-plugin-optimize',
            'serverless-offline',
            'serverless-localstack',
            'serverless-domain-manager',
            'serverless-plugin-datadog',
            'serverless-prune-plugin',
             'serverless-associate-waf',
        ],
        provider: {
            name: 'aws',
            runtime: 'nodejs16.x', <--  changed from nodejs14.x that worked
            ...
   
            iamRoleStatements: [
              ...
            ],
        },
        custom: {
            'serverless-offline': {
                useChildProcesses: true,
                noPrependStageInUrl: true,
               ..
            },
           ..
            localstack: {
                host: 'http://localhost',
                debug: true,
                ..
            },
        },
        package: {
            individually: true,
            exclude: ['./**'], <--  if i remove this the 'No file matches include / exclude patterns' disappears but the app crashes later 
        },
        functions: {
            api: {
                timeout: 30,
                handler: 'src/dist/serverless.handler',
                package: {
                    include: ['dist/**/*', '!dist/**/*.map', 'node_modules/**/*'],
                  },
            },
        },
    };
```

Comment: Please share your `serverless.yml` file

Answer (score 0):

This is because serverless-plugin-optimize is not compatible with Node14x and is deprecated.

[Github](https://github.com/FidelLimited/serverless-plugin-optimize).